# out of memory Heap error while uploading file using Spring Boot Api

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, file-upload, out-of-memory

I am getting out of memory heap when uploading large files. Is there any solution to upload large files without using heap memory or any library that doesn't read this stuff into RAM before writing it to mysql.

```
@PostMapping("/upload")
    public ResponseData uploadFile(@RequestParam("file")MultipartFile file) throws Exception {
        Attachment attachment =  null;
        attachment = fileStorageService.saveAttachment(file);
        String uriString = "/download/".concat(attachment.getId());
        return new ResponseData(attachment.getName(), uriString, file.getContentType(), file.getSize());
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Disable multipart parsing in Spring (Boot) and do a streaming file upload using Apache Commons Fileupload.